# How to create a TMap with a FString key and generic pointer value?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to create a TMap that has FString keys and a 'generic pointer' value. The reason being I have 3 classes: Earth, Wind and Fire. Depending on whether the FString of the TMap is "Earth", "Wind" or "Fire", I want to call certain methods of that respective class. I want something like this:

```
TMap<FString, ElementPointer> ElementMap;
```

such that:

```
// ElementMap == [
//  { Key: "Earth", Value: Earth* EarthPointer  },
//  { Key: "Wind", Value: Wind* WindPointer },
//  { Key: "Fire", Value: Fire* FirePointer  }
// ]
```

How can I construct this TMap as per above? As far as I can tell I might have to use:

```
template<typename ElementPointer>
```

but i'm not sure how to use this in my implementation. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "generic pointer"? Do those 3 classes not have a common base class?

Comment: When making a TMap you need to specify two type: the key type and value type. I know the first type is an FString and the second type is a pointer to a method. So when I say "generic pointer" I mean, what *type* can be used in the declaration of the TMap that translates to a pointer. Secondly they do, UObject.

Comment: pointer to a method? Can you elaborate on that, e.g.: how you intend to use this map?

Comment: I think my question is simple:

Can you construct a TMap with different class pointers as their values?

Comment: Then the answer is "no" - you need one specific type in a template. There are alternatives that could achieve the desired end result (such as storing a variant type), but you need to actually explain what your end result is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

```
//Do not TMap

.h

UFunction* ExecuteFunction;

UFUNCTION()
    void EarthEvent();
UFUNCTION()
    void WindEvent();
UFUNCTION()
    void FireEvent();
.cpp

void CallElement(FName NameElement)
{
    FName NameFunction = FName(NameElement.ToString() + FString("Event"));
    ExecuteFunction = FindFunction(NameFunction);
    if (ExecuteFunction != nullptr)
            ProcessEvent(ExecuteFunction, nullptr);
}

//...
CallElement("Wind");
//...
```